# isSubset of two arrays

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I want to get the subset of two arrays with a few test cases. I do not want to use the javascript .every function as that makes it too easy. My attempt works but I don't think it's optimal for time and space complexity O(n^2).

My test cases are as follows:

1) All values of `array1` should be defined in `array2`

2) If duplicate values exist in `array1`, they should also take into account in `array2`. for example, if `arr1 = ["a", "a"]` and `arr2 = ["b", "a"]` then isSubset is `false` because `"a"` appears twice in the first but only once in the second.

Here is my solution:

```
let arr1 = ["A", "B", "C"];
let arr2 = ["C", "A", "B", "D"];

function isSubset(a, b) {
  if(a.length > b.length) {
    return false;
  }

  var myHash = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    if(myHash[a[i]]) {
      myHash[a[i]] += 1;
    } else {
      myHash[a[i]] = 1;
    }
  }

  var myHash2 = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
    if(myHash2[b[i]]) {
      myHash2[b[i]] += 1;
    } else {
      myHash2[b[i]] = 1;
    }
  }


  for(var i in myHash) {
    for(var j in myHash2) {
      if(i == j && myHash[i] > myHash2[j]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }


  return true;
}

// test
var a = ["B", "A", "C", "A"];
var b = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
var c = isSubset(a, b);
console.log(c);
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KYPayp?editors=0010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are almost there. Instead of making 2 different hash objects, make a single hash object. Use the first array for incrementing `hash` values and the other for decrementing the values stored in the `hash`.
- Now, if the count stored in the `hash` is above zero, then it indicates that there is a deficiency of a certain value in array `b`. Else, we are all good for the subset objective.

```js
function isSubset(a, b) {
  if(a.length > b.length) {
    return false;
  }

   var hash = {};
   for(var i=0;i<a.length;++i){
     if(hash[a[i]] === undefined) hash[a[i]] = 0;
     hash[a[i]]++;
   }

  for(var i=0;i<b.length;++i){
    if(hash[b[i]] !== undefined) hash[b[i]]--;
  }
 
  var keys = Object.keys(hash);
  for(var each_key in keys){
     if(hash[keys[each_key]] > 0) return false;
  }

  return true;
}

// test
var a = ["B", "A", "C", "A"];
var b = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
console.log(isSubset(a, b));
a = ["B", "A", "C", "A"];
b = ["A", "B", "C", "D","A"];
console.log(isSubset(a, b));
```

- Time complexity is `O(n + m)` where `n` and `m` are lengths of respective lists. Space Complexity is `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the first list. This is because we never include any key that isn't present in our first array since it is irrelevant to the check we are performing.

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks!

Comment: @Shivam Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the nested loop as you've already computed the counts in `myHash2`. Just look it up. Replace the nested loop with

```
for(var i in myHash) {
  if (myHash[i] > myHash2[i])
    return false;
}
```

Time complexity is: **O(n)** where n is the length of the larger array. You could also eliminate the need for `myHash2` entirely if we subtract counters from `myHash` only if the key exists (as illustrated in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55423982/1112010) by *vivek_23*)

This can also be done in **O(nlogn) + O(n)** where `n` is the length of the larger array **without using extra memory**. O(n log n) is for the sort. Basically, we iterate over the two arrays simultaneously and increment the pointers in case the elements are equal. In case the element in `arr2` is larger, element is not found and we return `false`. If we reach till the end of `arr1`, all elements are found and we return `true`.

```
function isSubset(arr1, arr2) {
  arr1 = arr1.sort();
  arr2 = arr2.sort();
  let idx1 = 0, idx2 = 0;
  while (idx1 < arr1.length) {
    if (idx2 >= arr2.length) {
      return false;
    }
    if (arr1[idx1] > arr2[idx2]) {
      idx2++;
    } else if (arr1[idx1] == arr2[idx2]) {
      idx1++; idx2++;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table and count all items from the first array up and from the second down. Both arrays shares the same set, if all counts are zero.

```js
function isSubset(a, b) {
    function count(array, inc) {
        var i = array.length;
        while (i--) hash[array[i]] = (hash[array[i]] || 0) + inc;
    }

    var hash = {}, i, keys;

    count(a, 1);
    count(b, -1);

    keys = Object.keys(hash);
    i = keys.length;
    while (i--) if (hash[keys[i]]) return false;
    return true;
}

console.log(isSubset(["B", "A", "C", "A"], ["A", "B", "C", "A"]));      //  true
console.log(isSubset(["B", "A", "C", "A"], ["A", "B", "C", "D"]));      // false
console.log(isSubset(["B", "A", "C", "A"], ["A", "B", "C", "D", "A"])); // false
```